# Python command line application migration to web based

Tags: python, migration

Any guidelines on migrating a bunch of command line scripts to web based app? It is mainly a information retrieval application that I'm trying to build and does not really need to have much of user management - something in the lines of upload some documents and search in them. The motivation for going web based in mainly intuitive UI. Using something like plone and modifying it would probably be a bit too much, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using some minimalistic web framework.

If what you are trying to do is really simple you could have a look at Bottle

http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/index.html

Just import your scripts, think of some simple url scheme and write a few views.

Comment: bottle looks great .. can't wait to try it out